# How to handle routing of modal boxes just like in dribbble.com/shots without reloading page with React and Express js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Just like in dribbble.com/shots/  when I click I want to see modal box with information and url should also be changed without refresh. I am using React and Express.js.

Comment: Check this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery. The `gallery` section.

Comment: @WinChiu thanks man